# iPhone Synchronous FTP

Tags: iphone, xcode, ftp, synchronous

I am a beginner. I tried to use some synchronous FTP downloading (in order to create a file on the iphone from a file on the ftp server) in an application but I am not able to do it.
I read the doc (and CFTPSample) and I managed to use asynchronous download but not synchronous. Can anyone help me?

Cheers

Comment: Yes, we can help I'm sure. However, rather than asking if someone can help, it'd be particularly useful to know more about the problem you are experiencing. 

List any code, error messages and the alike that might be related to allow someone to trouble shoot. Also, it'd be helpful if you could provide a link to the document you are referring to. It is possible, (but not likely) that the document is flawed...

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSData](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class:

```
NSString *myFile = @"ftp://domain.com/file.txt";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myFile];
NSData *mydata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```